# I have a Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =1, address=0x8) error. I think its due bad memory management. What are some steps I can take to prevent this?

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is my code:

```
template<class T>
void list<T>::addEnd(T input) {
    node<T> *tempNode = new node<T>;
    node<T> * current = head;
    while (current->next == nullptr) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    tempNode->data = input;
    current->next = tempNode;
    tempNode->next = nullptr;
    tempNode->prev = current;
    tail = tempNode;
 }
```

The error occurs at the while(current->next == nullptr) line. 
I'm trying to implement a doubly linked list.

Comment: Are you sure that it should not be `while (current->next != nullptr)`?

Comment: You also don't verify that you have at least one item. What if `head` is `nullptr`?

Comment: `next` is the third member of  `node<T>`, isn't it? You're de-reference a `nullptr` using offset 8, i.e. third 32-bit member.

Comment: Use `valgrind`.

Comment: Obligatory "you should be using [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of managing memory yourself" comment.

Comment: In a doubly-linked list, you normally have direct access to the last node. Otherwise, the value of double-linking is quite diminished.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, `current` is not `nullptr`, then, say, `current->next` is `nullptr`. So after executing `current = current->next`, `current` becomes `nullptr`.

Then `current->next == nullptr` is evaluated and you got access violation as `current` is `nullptr` because you dereference zero pointer plus some little offset.

Answer (score -2):

Problematic section of code which will cause a memory leak.  You did not, for one, ever delete your local variable.  So unless you have a special ridiculous implementation of new() operator somewhere in your header, this will cause problems- especially if you were to get stuck in this while loop-

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question, and there is no leak.

Comment: Sorry I did not see the whereabouts of this implementation.   My bad